# Saving accessibility focus on Android after rotation

Tags: android

With explore-by-touch enabled, when I change the orientation of my screen it clears the accessibility focus (yellow highlight box). How can I save/restore that?

Answer (score -1):

use savedInstanceState:

see: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //save using outstate.write..

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // retrieve using savedInstanceStat.get...

    }
```

Comment: But how do I retrieve and set the accesibility focus? This solution would work fine for regular focus, but I can't seem to figure out how to restore the accessibility focus.

Comment: i believe you would use getCurrentFocus() which i think returns a view

Comment: getCurrentFocus() returns the currently focused view (blue bounding box) I want the accessibility focused view (yellow bounding box).